# error installing webdriver gem on cygwin

Tags: ruby, cygwin, selenium-webdriver

I got the below error when trying to install `webdriver gem` under `Cygwin`:

"gem install selenium-webdriver-2.26.0.gem": (Note that I want to install Webdriver gem under Cygwin using Ruby).

```
$ gem install selenium-webdriver-2.26.0.gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... 
ERROR:  Error installing selenium-webdriver-2.26.0.gem:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


/usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb
failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
    probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the
    mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-ffi_c-dir
        --without-ffi_c-dir
        --with-ffi_c-include
        --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
        --with-ffi_c-lib
        --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
        --with-libffi-config
        --without-libffi-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config 
     /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an  executable file.
(RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:14:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.2.0 for inspection. Results
logged to
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.2.0/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

Please guide me what thing I need to do to solve this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the error indicates that you need to install a header from libffi-devel. It may be part of gcc4-core.

Comment: thank so much for your reply and direction, I tried to include libffi and all gcc packages while installing Cygwin, but still failed when installing webdriver gem on Cygwin. Also, it's unluckily that Selenium guys also confirm that Cygwin environment is not supported, I need to use Ruby installation to run Selenium. So sad when knowing this info. anyway, thanks much for your guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that Cygwin is not supported to install webdriver gem (Please refer to my question to Selenium guys for details: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4812), So I tried to install on Ruby command prompt window instead.